# Serializing a Scala List to JSON in Play2

Tags: json, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I am trying to deserialize a list of Scala objects to a JSON map in Play2 - a pretty trivial use case with JSON, I'd say. My JSON output would be something along the lines of:

```
{
    "users": [
        {
            "name": "Example 1",
            "age": 20
        },
        {
            "name": "Example 2",
            "age": 42
        }
    ]
}
```

To achieve this I am looking at the Play2's JSON documentation titled *"The Play JSON library"*. To me their examples are pretty trivial, and I've confirmed that they work for me. Hence, I am able to deserialize a single `User` object properly.

But making a map containing a list in JSON seems a bit verbose in Play2, when I read the documentation. Is there something I am not grokking?

This is basically my simple Scala code:

```
case class User(name: String, age: Int)

object UserList {
  implicit val userFormat = Json.format[User]  

  val userList = List(User("Example 1", 20), User("Example 2", 42))
  val oneUser = Json.toJson(userList(0)) // Deserialize one Scala object properly to JSON.
  // JSON: { "user" : [ <-- put content of userList here. How?
  //                  ]
  //       }
}
```

So my question would be; how can I transform the content of the `userList` List above to a hash in the JSON in a more generic way than explicitly writing out each hash element, as the Play documentation suggests?

Comment: Wouldn't that be serializing instead of deserializing? Aren't you trying to convert your object to JSON?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
scala> import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.json._

scala> case class User(name: String, age: Int)
defined class User

scala> implicit val userFormat = Json.format[User]
userFormat: play.api.libs.json.OFormat[User] = play.api.libs.json.OFormat$$anon$1@38d2c662

scala> val userList = List(User("Example 1", 20), User("Example 2", 42))
userList: List[User] = List(User(Example 1,20), User(Example 2,42))

scala> val users = Json.obj("users" -> userList)
users: play.api.libs.json.JsObject = {"users":[{"name":"Example 1","age":20},{"name":"Example 2","age":42}]}
```

Comment: Oh wow - that was simple! I have to read the docs again. Wonder why this hasn't been told more clearly - or I missed it. Thanks!!

Comment: I must say, that just by reading the docs at www.playframework.com about Play's JSON support, I would have never came up with how to achieve what I wanted - and what you pasted. The docs seem to be quite rubbish.

Comment: @JohanPaul yeah, at some point you have to look at the method signatures and read the source code (to see what instances of the `Writes` typeclass are already defined by Play, in this particular case).

Comment: @IonuțG.Stan How did you import all play jars to scala console? I tried to reproduce your commands but I can't.

Comment: @angelokh I started the scala console from inside an sbt session in a Play project directory I had locally. I've described an alternative in this blog post http://igstan.ro/posts/2013-05-17-explore-jvm-libraries-in-a-quick-sbt-session.html. Hope it helps.

Comment: Can someone explain what each line does? I'm fairly new to Scala so I'm not sure how some of the code is working.

Comment: Way better than the play documentation. They should pay you.

Comment: For this example alone, it's sufficient to use `implicit val userReads = Json.writes[User]` rather than `Json.format...`.