# Run scala console with play 2.2 jars

Tags: scala, playframework-2.2

I saw people using play apis in the scala console. How can I import multiple play's jars to scala console?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17684559/772481

I tried this command, but it didn't work.

```
$ scala -cp /usr/local/Cellar/play/2.2.0/libexec/repository/local/com.typesafe.play/play_2.10/2.2.0/jars/*.jar
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach was right. `scala` REPL understands all `scalac` options, so `scala -cp` is the right option. However, you'll have to list all jars separately in the classpath separated by colon on Unix.

If you are lazy like me and don't want to spell out all jar files you can use something like this to build the classpath:

```
ls -1 ~/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe/config/jars/config-1.0.* | tr '\n' ':' | sed 's/:$/\n/'
```

Produces:

```
/home/alex/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe/config/jars/config-1.0.0.jar:/home/alex/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe/config/jars/config-1.0.2.jar
```

Use it in your original command:

```
scala -cp "$(ls -1 /usr/local/Cellar/play/2.2.0/libexec/repository/local/com.typesafe.play/play_2.10/2.2.0/jars/*.jar | tr '\n' ':' | sed 's/:$/\n/')"
```

If you want to avoid specifying a directory use `find` instead of `ls`:

```
find ~/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe/config/jars/ -name "*.jar" -exec echo {} \; | tr '\n' ':' | sed 's/:$/\n/'
```

Answer (score 0):

@aleksey's answer works for me. I also find another way to do it.

Go to your project target folder

```
$ cd <your play project>/target/universal/stage/lib
```

Now, run this command.

```
$ scala -cp `ls -1 | tr "\\n" ":"`
```