# Json#arr w/ List[Int] Input

Tags: json, scala, playframework-2.0

Looking at this helpful [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17684559/409976) on encoding a `List[A]` in the Play JSON [library](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaJson),

I tried to use [Json#arr](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.libs.json.Json$@arr(fields:play.api.libs.json.Json.JsValueWrapper*):play.api.libs.json.JsArray):

```
import play.api.libs.json._

scala> Json.arr( 1, 2, 3 )
res21: play.api.libs.json.JsArray = [1,2,3]
```

All works well so far, but what if I have a `List[Int]`:

```
scala> Json.arr( List(1,2,3) )
res22: play.api.libs.json.JsArray = [[1,2,3]] // not what I wanted
```

I attempted to pass the `List[Int]` as var-args (if that's the right term):

```
scala> Json.arr( List(1,2,3): _* )
<console>:18: error: type mismatch;
 found   : List[Int]
 required: Seq[play.api.libs.json.Json.JsValueWrapper]
       Json.arr( List(1,2,3): _* )
                     ^
```

But that did not work.

Then, I tried to create a `List[JsValueWrapper]`, and then pass that, via var-args, to `Json#arr`:

```
scala>  List(1,2,3).map(Json.toJsFieldJsValueWrapper)
<console>:18: error: No Json serializer found for type T. Try to implement an implicit Writes or Format for this type.
        List(1,2,3).map(Json.toJsFieldJsValueWrapper)
                             ^
```

Although that failed, the following works when applied to a single `Int`:

```
scala> Json.toJsFieldJsValueWrapper(1)
res27: play.api.libs.json.Json.JsValueWrapper = JsValueWrapperImpl(1)

scala> Json.arr(res27)
res28: play.api.libs.json.JsArray = [1]
```

How can I pass a `List[Int]` into `Json.arr` to get an output of `[1,2,3]`, i.e. a `JsArray` consisting of three `JsNumber`'s?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `Json.toJson`, validate as a `JsArray`, or return an empty one if invalid:

```
scala> val list = List(1, 2, 3)
list: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)

scala> Json.toJson(list).validate[JsArray].getOrElse(JsArray())
res6: play.api.libs.json.JsArray = [1,2,3]
```

You could also modify your lambda slightly with `Json.arr`:

```
scala> Json.arr(list.map(Json.toJsFieldJsValueWrapper(_)): _*)
res10: play.api.libs.json.JsArray = [1,2,3]
```

It seems as though without the parentheses, the compiler is having trouble inferring what `T` is. This is because the compiler tries to resolve the implicit before eta-expanding the anonymous function, so it doesn't know what argument will be passed to `Json.toJsFieldJsValueWrapper` yet. `Json.toJsFieldJsValueWrapper(_)` is fundamentally different because it expands to a slightly different `Function1`:

```
 x => Json.toJsFieldJsValueWrapper(x)
```

Here the compiler knows that `x` will be an `Int`, so the implicit `Writes[Int]` is resolved.

Comment: `This is because the compiler tries to resolve the implicit before eta-expanding the anonymous function`. Eta-expansion converts a `def` to `FunctionN`? When trying to resolve the implicit before eta-expansion, from where does `type T`, i.e. per ` No Json serializer found for type T`, come?

Comment: i.e. `def f[A](x: A): A = x` eta-expands to: 

`scala> f _
res0: Nothing => Nothing = <function1>`

Comment: The compiler doesn't know what the generic type is yet, so it likely just picks the only name it knows from here: https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/5428e7f8ed373efd7672eeeb4ea50d80bffcdea0/framework/src/play-json/src/main/scala/play/api/libs/json/Json.scala#L150

Comment: It's the same difference as: `def f[A](x: A): A = x)` in `f[Int](_)`, which has type ,`Int => Int`; and `f _`, which has type, `Nothing => Nothing`?

Comment: No.. more like `def f[A](x: A)(implicit w: Writes[A]): A = x; f _`

Answer (score 0):

How about just using `Json.toJson` and casting to a `JsArray` (if you need to)?

```
scala> Json.toJson(List(1,2,3)).as[JsArray]
res0: play.api.libs.json.JsArray = [1,2,3]
```

Comment: I'd prefer not to use `as` since it's un-safe, i.e. due to casting.